# Unshare workbook everyday

Tags: vba, excel

I want to unshare a excel workbook everyday at 11:00pm. 
First I use windows task scheduler to open the file at 10:59:45pm, and then run the following code. 
Would the following code work?

```
Sub Unshare()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If ThisWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then

ThisWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.Close

Else
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.Close

End Sub


Sub Workbook Open()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:00:00"), "Unshare"

End Sub
```

Also, all of the code is located in Thisworkbook.

Thanks!

Comment: Should be `Sub Workbook_Open()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Workbook_Open event in the private module of the Workbook object.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open( )
     Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:00:00"), "Unshare"
End Sub
```